# warning : The following options were not recognized by any processor: '[dagger.fastInit, kapt.kotlin.generated]'

Tags: android, warnings, android-build, dagger-hilt, kapt

I get this warning when I try to run or build an app in Android Studio. Why am I getting this? Do I need to heed this warning?

```
The following options were not recognized by any processor: '[dagger.fastInit, kapt.kotlin.generated]'
```

Comment: https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/2040 .. This is the issue tracker to the related issue.

Comment: I just moved `id "kotlin-kapt"` to be the last statement in the `plugins {}` and this warning disappeared.

Comment: Is it safe when remove kotlin-kapt?

Answer (score 138, accepted):

Move the `id "kotlin-kapt"` to the bottom of `plugins{}` in `build.gradle` Module-level.

Comment: well, this may be the most ridiculous warning I've seen. Definitely top 5.

Comment: ahah, why it's working?

Comment: Tried this but it didn't work for me

Comment: I have to agree, most nitpicky issue ever

Comment: This works - except when you're only using KSP in your project, and don't have any kapt at all.

Comment: If you're using KSP, just add/move the KSP plugin `"com.google.devtools.ksp"` to the end of the module-level plugins and indeed the warnings disappear.

Comment: if you use hilt with ksp in other modules and add such modules to another module where kapt is used for BindingAdapter for example (`dependencies { implementation(projects.design)` then it won't remove any warning: `The following options were not recognized by any processor: '[dagger.hilt.internal.useAggregatingRootProcessor, kapt.kotlin.generated, dagger.fastInit, dagger.hilt.android.internal.disableAndroidSuperclassValidation, dagger.hilt.android.internal.projectType]'`

Answer (score 18):

For me adding this to the build file (in the android block) fixed it:

```
hilt {
    enableAggregatingTask = true
}
```

reference: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-46940/Kapt-reports-a-warning-The-following-options-were-not-recognized-by-any-processor...#focus=Comments-27-5211169.0-0

Answer (score 15):

That happens when you compile a multi module project and some module has kapt but no entry point.

The issue is described [here](https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/2040) but is was already fixed [here](https://github.com/google/dagger/pull/2372/commits/3e4a5392896726d1cd3245ab06475380ea47fa57).

Just wait until next Android studio release or check if you have the latest versions of hilt and dagger

Comment: My project only has one module, and yet I still had that warning. The solution was to place `id "kotlin-kapt"` last inside the plugins section as mentioned by Ibrahim Disouki.

Answer (score 1):

For me solution was to remove `kotlin-kapt` & `dagger.hilt.android.plugin` from `build.gradle` files in modules that use only below annotations:

- from `dagger.hilt.android.qualifiers` package (`@ApplicationContext`, etc)
- from `javax.inject` package (`@Inject`, `@Singleton`, etc)

```
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.com.android.library)
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlin.android)
    // ⬇️ remove these 2 plugins 
    id('dagger.hilt.android.plugin')
    id('kotlin-kapt')
    // ⬆️
}

dependencies {
    // …
    // leave it here to use @Inject or replace with javax.inject dependency
    implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android"
    // remove only this ⬇️
    kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler"
}
```