# the following options were not recognized by any processor: '[dagger.fastinit, dagger.hilt.android.internal

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, kapt

I get this warning in my grade builds, it doesn't seem to cause any errors but would like to know what it means.

I have looked at [warning : The following options were not recognized by any processor: '[dagger.fastInit, kapt.kotlin.generated]'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70550883/warning-the-following-options-were-not-recognized-by-any-processor-dagger-f)  too and can confirm I don't have `kapt` as I have migrated to `ksp`

```
the following options were not recognized by any processor: 
'[dagger.fastinit, dagger.hilt.android.internal.disableandroidsuperclassvalidation, 
dagger.hilt.android.internal.projecttype,
 dagger.hilt.internal.useaggregatingrootprocessor]'
```

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same problem. When I removed the annotationProcessor used by other libraries, the warning disappeared.